# SSH server does not accept connections

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, docker, openssh

I have built a Docker image locally using Docker, which runs a SSH server + some other services. The Dockerfile is internal, so I can't post it here. But the basic things I do is:

```
RUN apt-get install -q -y openssh-server openssh-client

RUN cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.factory-defaults

RUN chmod a-w /etc/ssh/sshd_config.factory-defaults

RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd

RUN echo 'root:changeme' |chpasswd

ADD ./bootstrap.sh /root/bootstrap.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/root/bootstrap.sh"]
```

And inside of bootstrap.sh:

```
...
echo "Starting SSH service..."
/usr/sbin/sshd -D > /dev/null 2>&1 &
ps -A | grep sshd
...
```

... and it works so far. **I can connect to the SSH server (running inside of the Ubuntu container) from the host machine.**

So far, so good. Now I have uploaded the image to Dockerhub and I run it on tutum.co.

Now the problem: The SSH server starts, but I'm not able to connect to it. Even locally inside of the container. By the way, I have a browser shell, so I'm still able to execute commands.

I execute inside of the container:

```
ssh root@localhost -v                        
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012                      
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config                          
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *                     
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.                                  
debug1: Connection established.                                                 
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0                                                
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1                                 
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1                            
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1                                 
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1                            
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1                               
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1                          
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debia
n-5ubuntu1.4                                                                    
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4 pat OpenSSH*                     
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0                            
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4            
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent                                                   
Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to connect as `root` which is forbidden as a standard option in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in the container. You either need to set up a `user` in your `Dockerfile` or allow `root-login` or copy a public key in your `Dockerfile`. I would discourage you from allowing `root`-login and from copying your public key via the `Dockerfile`. My solution would be to edit your `Dockerfile` in the following manner:

```
# Set root passwd
RUN echo 'root:changeme' |chpasswd

# Add user so that container does not run as root
RUN useradd -m michaelkunzmann
RUN echo "michaelkunzmann:test" | chpasswd
RUN usermod -s /bin/bash michaelkunzmann
RUN usermod -aG sudo michaelkunzmann
ENV HOME /home/michaelkunzmann
ENV HOSTNAME michaelkunzmannsbox
```

Then build the image and login via `ssh michaelkunzmann@localhost -v`. (If this does not work make sure you're using the right `port`. You can specify it e.g. by using `docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:5000:22 -P --name="name-your-container!" your-image`. You can then login via 
`ssh michaelkunzmann@localhost -p 5000`.)

By the way, if you're running several processes in your container you should get familiar with [Supervisor](http://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/).

Comment: If this does not work get back to me. I had the same problem today and I got it working so I got a few possible solutions up my sleeve.

Comment: Root is not an issue for my use case, actually root is required for my use case. The issue must be with tutum.co, since it works locally.

Comment: Ok, I'll get back to you later today!

Comment: There could be a possible issue with the length of the ciphers. This is a server-bug. It is not well known but a few people have encountered it. Can you try setting `Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc` in your `ssh_config` and tell me if it works. Basically the idea is to reduce the cipher lengths by excluding the options that use longer ones.

Answer (score 0):

My docker file for reference for someone else like me:

```
FROM centos:6

RUN yum install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd

RUN ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
RUN ssh-keygen -t dsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key

RUN sed -ri 's/UsePAM yes/#UsePAM yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sed -ri 's/#UsePAM no/UsePAM no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

RUN echo 'root:root' | chpasswd

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```